# show group selection as separate files in Kendo Upload Control for deleting one file from the bunch

Tags: html, kendo-ui

I'm using the Kendo UI Upload Control and wanted to allow for multiple files in single Upload, but when adding multiple files at the same time, they are grouped together in the same line item. Is there a way to have each separate file as its own line item when group selecting?,because i want to delete one file from this bunch of file which is uploaded by users. In the screenshot that is linked, there are 4 items,but i want to upload each items in new row.[image]

```
$('#selectedFiles').kendoUpload({
    localization: {
        select: 'Attach'
        },
    multiple: true,
    success: function (e)
    {
    },
    select: function (e)
    {
    }
});

<div class=" form-group">
<div class="col-md-8">
  <input name="file" id="selectedFiles" type="file"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about using External Template showing files?
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/upload/templates

Comment: @japi : it's works with Aync Kendo upload but i have to Upload files and then after user press save button and all these files are uploaded so i can not use Async that time..